# how to make atomic instruction

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronization, atomic

in multithreading if many threads change the value of a global variable,(instruction is in execute procedure) like this:

```
 value:=value+1;
```

for sure this one must be an atomic instruction, so what should I add to my code to make this instruction atomic?

Comment: What is the type of that `value` variable ?

Comment: For atomic increment (which you've shown in your code) use [`TInterlocked.Increment`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked.Increment). There are also other functions like [`TInterlocked.Decrement`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked.Decrement) for decrementing, or [`TInterlocked.Exchange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked.Exchange) for value exchanging, etc.

Comment: Another way to deal with such situations is to avoid the sharing in the first place. Stop using globals. Keep variables local. Sometimes you need to share, but if it can be avoided, usually it should be avoided.

Comment: Okay, in this case I need to share, is there another function that can make any instruction atomic, not only incrementation, and hwo can I accept an answer, what should I do?

Comment: You cannot make any instruction atomic. Only those that can reasonably be implemented. The AtomicXXX family are those with hardware support. For more complex operations you need to use a lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern Delphi you should use the intrinsic function [`AtomicIncrement`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AtomicIncrement). There are a whole family of such functions in the RTL that provide atomic operations. For instance atomic exchange, atomic compare and swap and so on.

For your code you would write:

```
AtomicIncrement(value);
```

The benefit of using intrinsic functions is that the compiler inlines the asm instructions at the call site.

In older versions of Delphi you should use `InterlockedIncrement`. Again, there are a family of similarly named functions.